# Wordpress : issue with archive page for multiple custom post type with pagination

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, archive

I'm new on wordpress and i'm trying to create an archive page for multiple custom post type.

I have two custom post type, 'fair' and 'exhibition'
I currently have two archive page, with pre get post action :

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $q ) 
{
    if (    !is_admin() // VERY important, targets only front end queries
         && $q->is_main_query() // VERY important, targets only main query
         && $q->is_post_type_archive( 'fair' ) // Which post type archive page to target
    ) {
        $q->set( 'oderby', 'meta_value_num' );
        $q->set( 'meta_key', '_datepicker');
        $q->set('showposts', 3);
        $q->set('is_post_type_archive', false);
        $q->set('order', 'ASC');  
        // Rest of your arguments to set
}
});
```

both of the custom post type have the same meta box and i want to display both post type on the archive page "fair" or in a new one if necessary

i tried to add

```
        $q->set('post_type', array('fair', 'exhibition'));
```

to the function.

When i do that i have my both post type but my custom archive page ("archive-fair.php") do not seems to be called

How can i perform the archive page for both post type properly with functional pagination ?

Thanks and sorry for my english, i hope it's understandable.

Edit : my archive-post.php page look like :

```
 <?php get_header(); 
 while ( have_posts() ) 
 {
   the_post();
    $p_type =     get_post_type(get_the_ID());
   if ($p_type == 'fair') 
       $img = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "wp_fair_attachment", true);
   else 
      $img = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "wp_exhibition_attachment", true); 
 ?> 
  some html
 <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach is to use `template_include`

Try this code and let me know if it works:

```
add_filter( 'template_include', function( $template ){
    $your_types = array( 'fair', 'exhibition' );
    $post_type = get_post_type();

    if ( ! in_array( $post_type, $your_types ) )
        return $template;

    return get_stylesheet_directory() . '/single-fair.php'; 
});
```

Comment: I don't use template_include, i have a page "archive-fair", and i perform a loop inside. can i do something like this in my case ?

Comment: what you're doing is quite possible too, show the complete code with post_type setting that you're using

Comment: What part of the code do y need ? I only have the creation of custom post type, the code in the first message to change the request and that in archive-fair.php

    <?php get_header();
    while ( have_posts() )
 {
  the_post();
  $p_type =  get_post_type(get_the_ID());
  if ($p_type == 'fair')
   $img = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "wp_fair_attachment", true);
  else
   $img = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "wp_exhibition_attachment", true);
  ?>
    (... code html)
    <?php } ?>